# SQLAlchemy delete limit rows

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can I delete last 10 rows from my query?

I have query:

```py
query = session.query(MyTableClass) \ 
.filter(MyTableClass.country=='USA') \ 
.order_by(MyTableClass.id.asc()) \ 
.limit(10)
```

How can I delete 10 rows only?

I tried:
`query.delete()` - 
error: Can't call Query.update() or Query.delete() when limit() has been called

`session.delete(query)` - 
error: Class 'sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query' is not mapped

Comment: What db are you using?

Answer (score 7):

You can't delete a query that has a limit() on it, but you can delete one with a filter(). So you:

- make your query into a subquery with the limit(10) on it. Just put a .subquery() on the end
- make a second query that filters for your subquery and you can delete that.

If this seems silly to you, you're not alone. I believe this was reported as a bug a few years ago and never got fixed. It has to do with the object type limit() returns.

Comment: Wow, this is weird.. Trying the "filter by subquery" then raises issues with metadata stores and session synchronization. Feels much cleaner to just execute SQL text directly instead of using the ORM.